# Display n characters of Text field from Contact Form 7

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7

I'm not sure if this question was asked but I couldn't find the solution.

I want to display the first 2 characters from the Contact form 7 text field in the mail.

For example, a person types "TODAY" in the text field.
In the email, I would like to display on the first 2 characters which are "TO" in the mail section when the admin receive the email.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: You could add hidden fields and use JavaScript that limits the length of say the name field but populated the value of hidden field with said trimmed value then just use that value in your email?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this

Add this script however you are adding scripts to your page, in a static .js file, or you can add this to the end of your contact form.

```
<script>
      jQuery('input[name="your-name"]').blur(function () {
        var s = jQuery(this).val().substr(0, 2);
        if (jQuery('#name-value').length) {
            jQuery('#name-value').val(s);
        } else {
            jQuery(this).after('<input name="name-value" id="name-value" type="hidden" value="' + s + '">');
        }
      });
</script>
```

Replace 'first-name' with whatever you are using here and replace 'name-value' with what you want to use for the email form.

Then in your admin email, use the form tag 
`[name-value]` and it will show up in the email.  Contact form 7 turns all form fields into tags by name.

Comment: I have tried it, but there is a small problem, the first time is good. but when I tried again with another text, it keep showing the first try value. Example,

1st try, text is "John", output is "Jo"
2nd try, text is "Vincent", output is still "Jo".

Do we need to clear memory or database?

Comment: I've updated the answer to handle revisions. Use `[name-value]` as your email tag.

Comment: Thank you very much. This is the perfect code I need. By the way, I have ask another CF7 related question. Appreciated if you could help on it as well.